# Initial stress-derived nouns rules and patterns

Tags: stress

Is this the correct term for words which are nouns when the first syllable is stressed, and verbs when the second syllable is stressed? Examples include PERmit and perMIT, and CONtract, and conTRACT.

There are frequently-occurring suffixes such as '-ject' and '-tract', but are there any other relevant rules and patterns?

Comment: Sorry, but as a native BrE speaker I do not recognise this stress pattern. I pronounce permit and contract without any stress whether they be as nouns or verbs.

Comment: @PeterJennings — In BrE, does one really sign a CONtract and CONtract a disease? In AmE, we sign a CONtract and conTRACT a disease. We buy a PERmit that perMITs us to park.

Comment: @TinfoilHat No I personally would say "sign a contract and contract a disease". However I will concede that some may put stress on either of the syllables. It's probably a matter of personal preference, dialect or opinion.

Comment: @TinfoilHat As a native AmE speaker, my experience is that the stress pattern is often so subtle as to be unnoticeable, especially in cases like permit where the noun and verb are very closely related. Contract as in contract a disease is pronounced distinctly, but contract as in sign an agreement to do something is usually indistinguishable from contract as in the agreement signed.

Comment: @RyanJensen That other sense of the verb "contract" is different. It is worth noting that stress is phonemic in English; pairs like *insight* and *incite* would be homophones if not for the difference in syllable stress.

Comment: ("Record," "permit,," "suspect" and "insult" might be better examples.)

Comment: @alphabet That distinction is exactly what I was trying to highlight. When the noun and verb have closely linked meanings as in permit and suspect, the difference in stress tends to be subtle or absent, though it is more pronounced in homophones without directly related meanings, like incite/insight or contract/contract (with regard to disease).

Comment: @PeterJennings To me the difference in "permit" and "suspect" is very sharp; I don't think I'd ever pronounce them with any other stress pattern, and I don't think I've heard other people do that either, in any dialect.

Comment: @RyanJensen — What’s interesting is that we might say *I bought a PERmit so now I am PERmitted* [adjective from passive meaning] vs. *I bought a PERmit, so now I am perMITTED [allowed] to park here.*

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the correct term for words which are nouns when the first syllable is stressed, and verbs when the second syllable is stressed?

Yes. [Wikipedia has more](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial-stress-derived_noun) on initial-stress-derived nouns.

There are far too many of these to identify more specific patterns. That Wikipedia article has a long list that is nowhere close to being complete.

Comment: Also as Wikipedia notes, most of these stress patterns vary based on region/dialect; very few are universal rules of English, a non-tonal language.