# Disyllabic nouns that differ from their verbs only in which syllable is emphasised

Tags: verbs, adjectives, nouns, pronunciation

Some English nouns are identical to their verbs (and their adjectives) both in spelling and pronunciation, for example:

> "This is fake"; "to fake"; "this is a fake"
>
> "To tear"; "a tear"
>
> "To parody"; "a parody"
>
> "A misfire"; "to misfire"

There are some examples where the (disyllabic) noun is spelt exactly like its verb but the noun is pronounced with the opposite stress (at least, in the standard accents which I hear day-to-day in the UK), for example:

> "An **es**cort"; "to es**cort**"
>
> "My **re**call of the event is faulty"; "I cannot re**call** what happened"
>
> "To re**peat**"; "a **re**peat" (this last one is a bit weak since people use either stress pattern in different contexts)

This phenomenon is observed with some verb-adjective pairs too:

> "To per**fect**"; "this is **per**fect"

In all three cases, I would be interested in:

- The corresponding formal linguistic term (if there is one)
- Examples! Although I *know* there are plenty more than I've shown here, they elude me. What's worse is that there's a fair few I've thought of but can no longer re**call**.

Bonus: are there any examples of noun-adjective pairs that are pronounced with opposite stress?

Comment: "To tear"; "a tear". You should tear up this poor example before you bring tears to everyone's eyes. (Ah, homographs.)

Comment: @Laurel Hah, I knew the risks as I wrote it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for a ***list***. Which I think is *always* Off Topic here.

Comment: Related / duplicate [Initial stress-derived nouns rules and patterns.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/608226/initial-stress-derived-nouns-rules-and-patterns)

Comment: Answered at: [A term for words that change pronunciation with part of speech](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239164/a-term-for-words-that-change-pronunciation-with-part-of-speech/239173#239173)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called **initial-stress-derived nouns.** [As Wikipedia explains:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial-stress-derived_noun)

> Initial-stress derivation is a phonological process in English that moves stress to the first syllable of verbs when they are used as nouns or adjectives. (This is an example of a suprafix.) This process can be found in the case of several dozen verb-noun and verb-adjective pairs and is gradually becoming more standardized in some English dialects, but it is not present in all. The list of affected words differs from area to area, and often depends on whether a word is used metaphorically or not. At least 170 verb-noun or verb-adjective pairs exist.

Wikipedia gives a long list.

Comment: Great. This perfectly answers my main question. Do you know what it's called where, e.g. with "to parody, a parody", the verb is identical to the noun in both spelling and pronunciation?

Comment: @FShrike Those are "bare nominalizations" or "zero-derived deverbal nouns." See [this dissertation by Cetnarowska.](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/197749102.pdf)